# Unable to change Azure Function runtime version after deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I've just deployed several functions to my Azure Function. I have used the 2.0 Function Runtime to create the app but I'm unable to change the version from the previous version I had set (1.0). Is there a way I can change this without deleting the function and starting again?
[image: Unable to change function runtime version]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done to protect users from breaking their app, as a v1 Functions are mostly guaranteed to break in a v2 app, and vice versa.

If you really want to do this anyway (e.g. because you deployed and forgot to change the app first), you can simply change the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` App Setting to `~1` / `~2` to target the runtime that you want.

Comment: I figured it was to prevent stuff breaking - your solution is much easier. Thanks David.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little convoluted but it turns out there is a way of doing this but it does mean deleting your deployed functions and redeploying.

1. Set the function to be in read/write mode - this will allow you to manually delete functions.
   [image: Edit Azure Function Mode]
2. View the functions summary in the menu item - notice all your functions are now editable so you can delete them. Delete all of them.
   [image: Delete old functions]
3. Head back to the function settings page where you can now change the runtime version.
4. Now redeploy your functions and you are good to go!